# Select datetime column from SQL Server 2008 R2 table

Tags: c#, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a `DateTime` column on a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 database. My c# front end is inserting a row in this table with a datetime parameter.

```
DateTime T = DateTime.Now;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "cargridsnapshot";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t", T);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The datetime column in the row in the table is this:

```
2013-09-04 16:21:23.450
```

but

```
select * from table 
where TIMECOLUMN = '2013-09-04 16:21:23.450'
```

returns no results.

Comment: sorry having problems with formatting.

Comment: Is it possibly in a transaction that has yet to be committed?

Comment: Also DateTime T = DateTime.Now  ---

Comment: Why are you identifying rows by timestamp? What if two users insert a row with the same timestamp?

Comment: Could be a localization issue with the date.

Comment: For future reference you can select code and press the `{}` button and it will format it for you

Comment: Transaction has been committed.

Comment: Could be a rounding issue also.  Are you sure that you are querying *exactly* for that value?

Comment: try `select * from table where TIMECOLUMN =convert(datetime,'2013-09-04 16:21:23.450',121)`

Comment: It was format of the datetime in the select statement: this works select * from JOB_ASSIGNMENT_LOGS 
where TIMEMARK = '04/09/2013 16:21:23.450'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server can represent datetime in a variety of ways when comparing a string to your database value. Some have the month before the day, some day before month. The localization of your SQL Server is causing your issue; you can read more about it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx). Specifically, look for `SET DATEFORMAT`.

Comment: But there is only one starting YYYY format and that is YYYY-MM-DD.  I suspect the op transposed.

Comment: Not according to Microsoft's documentation on the link.

Comment: OK +1.  But I cannot find a conversion for that format.  This fails for me: select cast('2013-15-04 16:21:23.450' as datetime)  and I cannot even find a convert format that works.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server only stores time to approximately 1/300th of a second-you are probably using a value that cannot accurately be represented with the available bits.

**Edit**

You can check this behavior with the following code:

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-09-04 16:21:23.450') -- returns 2013-09-04 16:21:23.450
select CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-09-04 16:21:23.451') -- returns 2013-09-04 16:21:23.450
select CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-09-04 16:21:23.452') -- returns 2013-09-04 16:21:23.453
select CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-09-04 16:21:23.453') -- returns 2013-09-04 16:21:23.453
select CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-09-04 16:21:23.454') -- returns 2013-09-04 16:21:23.453
select CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-09-04 16:21:23.455') -- returns 2013-09-04 16:21:23.457
```

**Bottom line**

Don't try to identify rows with a datetime...

Answer (score 1):

What if you use this

`Select * from table where convert(date,yourcolumn)=convert(date,your_datetime)`

but kindly note it will compare on date only

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server [`datetime`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) type is accurate only only to increments of `.000`, `.003`, or `.007` seconds.

So when you save a value with `.450`, that will be fine.  But if you saved with `.451`, that would get rounded back down to `.450`, and then it wouldn't match up.

You can avoid this by using a [`datetime2`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) column type.

Also - you probably shouldn't be storing `DateTime.Now` in your database.  [Read here](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).